# Android Wear Gestures (Version 1.4) in Apps, not just for Notifications?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, gesture

How can i use Android Wear Wrist Gestures in Wear Apps? Is it possible to detect them for e.g. scrolling on flicking the wrist?

Answer (score 0):

If you register the callback `onKeyDown()` in your activity, you should be notified of the following [events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html): `KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT`, 
`KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS`, `KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_IN` and `KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_OUT`. These new gestures are mapped to these events. So here is a quick override:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown Keycode: " + keyCode);

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT:
            // Do something that advances user view to the next item in an ordered list
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS:
            // Do something that advances user view to the previous item in an ordered list
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_IN:
            // Do something that activates the item that currently has focus or expands to
            // the next level of a navigation hierarchy
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_OUT:
            // Do something that backs out one level of a navigation hierarchy or collapses
            // the item that currently has focus.
            return true;
        default:
            // If you did not handle, then let it be handled by the next possible element as
            // deemed by Activity.
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, it works. But how can scroll to a new (existing) CardFragment. I have e GridViewPager an will scroll through this Cards with gestures

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe GirdViewPager. scrollTo(i,j) would scroll to the page you want? Note that the main use case for such gesture is to scroll in a list and not in a grid.

Comment: You might want to open a separate question on how to programmatically navigate a GridViewPager since that is very different from your original questions and many people may not look at this one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find the HandsFree Wear application interesting (I'm the creator), with witch you can (almost) fully use your android smartwatch through wrist gestures.

https://github.com/jsalatas/HandsFreeWear